# Why is it possible to specify an interface method's implementation in C#?

Tags: c#, java, .net, oop, interface

Coming from a Java background, I'm aware that an interface's method cannot contain code within the interface, as is described below (taken from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html)):

> A method declaration within an interface is followed by a semicolon,
>   but no braces, because an interface does not provide implementations
>   for the methods declared within it.

Does this also apply for C#? As I have constructed an interface to test this in Visual Studio, and after specifying code in an interface method's body, the compiler did not stop me from doing this.

Comment: Interfaces cannot specify implementation. Post your example code.

Comment: Thanks Chris, no need to post the code as I just needed confirmation.

Comment: Why didn't you just try to compile it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nope. Interfaces can only outline methods and properties in c#. Method bodies, or implementations are not allowed. Paste some code perhaps for a closer look at the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed confirmation!

Comment: This is no longer true it seems. Assuming you have the correct version of C#. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/default-implementations-in-interfaces/

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces cannot have implementation in C#

If you create a interface like below

```
 interface IInterface
    {
        void MyMethod()
        {

        }
    }
```

You will get compilation error `interface members cannot have a definition`

Answer (score 1):

interface members cannot have a definition. This rule is true for C# , java and all object oriented lanuages

Answer (score 0):

Interface methods are abstract and cannot contain method bodies; they don't even have default implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Did you used the right keyword while starting your code?! Something like:

```
    interface IExampleInterface
{

string ThisMethodReturnsString(string arg);

}
```